# Injecting repository instance into class

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I've started designing parts of a fairly large system and was wondering what would be the best way to use repositories.

Which method would be better:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dataRepository = new DataRepository();
            var classA = new ClassA(dataRepository);
            classA.Save();
        }

        public interface IDataRepository
        {
            void Save(ClassA myInstance);
        }

        public class DataRepository : IDataRepository
        {
            public void Save(ClassA myInstance)
            {
                //Do some stuff
            }
        }

        public class ClassA
        {
            private IDataRepository _dataRepository;
            public ClassA(IDataRepository dataRepository)
            {
                _dataRepository = dataRepository;
            }

            public void Save()
            {
                _dataRepository.Save(this);
            }
        }
```

Or should I do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dataRepository = new DataRepository();
    var classB = new ClassB();
    dataRepository.Save(classB);
}

public interface IDataRepository
{
    void Save(ClassB myInstance);
}

public class DataRepository : IDataRepository
{
    public void Save(ClassB myInstance)
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    //some stuff    
}
```

Or is there any other way I could this more elegantly?

Comment: If you want purity then you create a UOW class and pass the repository into that. What orm are you intending on running this over?

Comment: It's probably going to be Dapper

Comment: All I would say is, only introduce something when there is a real need for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your choices aren't worse or better, but they're different.

- **1** is an [active record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) implementation.
- **2** is more *DDDish* ([domain-driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)).

In my case, since DDD is friendly with my own way of structuring my mind, I go with **#2**. Usually this approach is better (it's my point of view) because it favors a better separation of concerns and less coupling: your POCO classes have no dependency with their repositories, while *active record pattern* has the drawback of turning your classes very specific for its use case (they're less reusable).

> Or is there any other way I could this more elegantly?

This is a very broad question, I would need to write a book to give you a possible and exact answer to it.

BTW, I believe that you should take a look at [*unit of work* pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), which will empower your solution even more since you'll be able to implement *tech-agnostic domain transactions*.